# is there a way in dynamic-linq library to select... where Column startswith

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I am trying to select the fields that start with something using dynamic querylibrary, I am limited to using the column name and fields to be in variables. I have tried:

```
var x = myqueriable.Where("" + X1  + " LIKE @0 and "  + X2 + "= @1 ", Y1 + "%", Y2);
```

i have error: "system.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException:  Expression of type Boolean expected>

Is there a way to accomplish the mentioned?

Comment: So `X` is a property name and `Y` is a value to compare with?

Comment: yes  they are @Aleks

Comment: Just grab filter it from the queryable type

Comment: sorry, but i don't know what do you mean by grab filter it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = myQueryable.Where(y => y.StartsWith(param0));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are bad answers.  Please add an explanation for *why* your solution solves the problem.

Comment: I mean, his question was one line of code. I posted the correct syntax. It works because, it's... right? I dunno. It's the right way to do it. It works because that's how it is.

Comment: Why did you decide that `myqueriable` is `IQueryable<string>`? From question: _select the fields that start with_. Also question is marked with `dynamic-linq` tag, so I'm think that `myQueryable` is `IQueryable<T>` and `X` is a property name. I'm not sure so I asked OP in comments

Comment: thanks for your attempt @Jon, But i dont have the field to be selected, it is stored in variables X1 and X2

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question, didn't see you were using Dynamic LINQ

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a dynamic lambda expression like

```
p => p.Property.StartsWith("some prefix");
```

you can do this without external libraries by using built-in Expressions API. See this extension method:

```
public static class QueryableExt
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildLambda<T>(this IQueryable<T> input, string propertyName, string startsWith)
    {
        var elemenType = input.ElementType;
        var property = elemenType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"There is no property {propertyName} in {elemenType.Name}");
        if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expected string property but actual type is {property.PropertyType.Name}");

        var startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });

        var p = Expression.Parameter(elemenType, "p"); // p => ...
        var memberExpression = Expression.Property(p, property); // ... p.Propery
        var startsWithValue = Expression.Constant(startsWith); // "some prefix"
        var startsWithExpression = Expression.Call(memberExpression, startsWithMethod, startsWithValue); // ... p.Property.StartsWith("some prefix")
        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(startsWithExpression, p); // p => p.Property.StartsWith("some prefix")

        return result;
    }
}
```

Please note that `BuildLambda` is more type safe than just string concatenations: this method actually check that `propertyName` exists and has a valid type. Now you can use it like

```
var x = myqueriable.Where(myqueriable.BuildLambda(X, Y))
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) you should be able to use **StartsWith()**.

Example code:

```cs
var result = Entity1s.Where("Url.StartsWith(\"x\")");
```

This is translated into SQL like:

```sql
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'x%'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Url], [t0].[Rating]
FROM [Entity1] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Url] LIKE @p0
```